# Using ES6 Syntax to Map an Array of Values to Array of Truncated Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I am trying to use `.map()` and ES6 syntax to return a truncated version of each object in my array. I can do this to get one value from the original object passed on:

```
  return dbJobs.map(job =>
    job.data.modType
  );
```

But how would I use ES6 syntax to handle taking an array of objects where each object looks like this:

```
{
  id: 123,
  name: "name value",
  data: {
    modType: "report",
    category: "value"
  }
}
```

... and return an array of objects where each object has two properties from the original objects, like this:

```
{
  name: "name value",
  modType: "report"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So with [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) you can create a new structure based on its function's return value.

> The `map()` method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

Think about the following:

```js
const array = [{
  id: 123,
  name: "name value",
  data: {
    modType: "report",
    category: "value"
  }
}];

const result = array.map(e => {
  return {
    name: e.name,
    modeType: e.data.modType
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

Or the same with destructuring:

```js
const array = [{
  id: 123,
  name: "name value",
  data: {
    modType: "report",
    category: "value"
  }
}];

const result = array.map(({name, data: {modType}}) => {
  return {
    name,
    modType
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: `({name, data: {modType}}) => { return { name, modType } }` even shorter as `({name, data: {modType}}) => ({ name, modType })`

Comment: but now it is a copy of míne.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and map objects with [short hand properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).

```js
var dbJobs = [{ id: 123, name: "name value", data: { modType: "report", category: "value" } }],
    result = dbJobs.map(({ name, data: { modType } }) => ({ name, modType })); 

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will do what you need:

```js
let obj = [{
  id: 123,
  name: "name value",
  data: {
    modType: "report",
    category: "value"
  }
}];

let res = obj.map(item => {
  return {
  modType: item.data.modType,
  category: item.data.category
  }
});
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this simple js code

```js
arr = arr.map(item => {
  const ob  = {} // create temporary object
  ob.name = item.name; // asign props from array object
  ob.modType = item.data.modType; // asign props from array object
  return ob // just return create object
})
```